# Global Method to Clone object in vuejs rather then reference it, to avoid code duplication

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building simple CRUD div list with Vuejs, which allows me to perform all operations on single page as search through results by the means of filter.

The problem I face is that in order to do perform update I have to have two containers for each data object in the loop.

So 1st container acts like view, 2nd has the form with same values as view for editing purposes. I basically toggle them to switch from view to edit mode

It looks something like that:

```
<input v-model="search">
<items v-for="product in products | filterBy search in searchFields">
   <item>
       <div v-show="!edit">
          Display Data "div"
       <div>
       <div v-show="edit">
          Edit Data "form"
       <div>
   <item>
</items>
```

I have a problem with using "filterBy" when looping through items to search through them. Because data in 1st and 2nd container is bound upon editing field in edit mode the element disappears. As filter does not care whether the item is in edit mode or in view mode. It simply filters items, and when the value of item is changed and no longer equal to search value its gone.

I have solved the problem by simply cloning object of view element and passed cloned object to form element instead of referencing it by adding objectClone method on child item. Which sort of fixes my problem as the data in edit mode no longer bound to view mode. But this creates another problem, now I have to copy objectClone method on each new child element of the loop in order for this to work.  Is there a way to clone element within vuejs without creating a dedicated method or is it possible to create global method objectClone to use it across all Vue elements?

Additional problem I get with my approach is that element after editing now cloned and I cant remove it from parent data container. As it no longer references the previous element that got cloned.

Comment: Did you solve this? If yes please share your solution. Thx